# PHP/cURL curl_exec() error?

Tags: php, curl

This is my first time using cURL so it might be a silly error on my part but the following code:

```
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $output;
```

Prints "1". It is my understanding that CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER should ensure that curl_exec returns either 0 or the content but here it's behaving as if CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER hasn't been set to true. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is correct for doing what you describe as the desired result, it sounds like the server at `$url` returns `1` in the body of the response - what do you get if you load it in a browser? What is in `$url`? What does `var_dump($output);` (instead of `echo`) show?

Comment: @DaveRandom Huh. var_dump($output); shows bool(true)...implying that the content of the page isn't 1 and it really is the function returning true, yes? The $url is https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=159153294131249&format=atom10 (a feed from a facebook fan page which I am hoping to turn into a simple XML object). Thank you!

Comment: @user1492165 Try: http://itslennysfault.com/easy-way-to-load-facebook-news-feed-through-rss-atom10

Comment: ...and `$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);` not an option? Although your code should work, can you show your full actual code (minus passwords etc)?

Comment: @miqbal That is actually where I got the idea from in the first place; it didn't work with that exact code either.

Comment: @DaveRandom I will try simplexml_load_file...sorry, this is literally my first experience with xml and such and I'm not aware of all the options :) Edit: jk this server isn't running PHP 5. The curl problem shouldn't be related to that though, right?

Comment: The behaviour of libcurl in this respect has not changed for a long time (possibly ever) so I doubt that PHP<5 is the problem. It is definitely *a* problem, but it's not the problem here. You should be able to just pass the URL to `simplexml_load_file()` as long as the server has `allow_url_fopen` enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Code appears to be correct, try curl_getinfo()

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$outputInfo = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output . PHP_EOL;
echo $outputInfo;
```

It maybe possible that the resource is literally returning a body with "1"

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which I resolved by using

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
```

The problem was that the server gave back a custom error page, which cURL interpreted as success. By using this option the custom error page header code of 404 was detected correctly and the URL failure was detected.

OP refers to using facebook as their target, so I suspect a custom error message was used as well by the target url.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org/), which is an OOP wrapper around cURL. (Though since you're just using a GET request, `file_get_contents($url);` would work fine). There's no real issue with your code, though. Are you sure the URL is valid?

Also, check to make sure that `curl_setopt` is returning true for each call to it, and try setting the CURLOPT_URL using that function.

Comment: `$output = file_get_contents($url); echo $output;' doesn't print anything. Slash it must cause some sort of error because no php after it executes. But you're right, I feel like I should just be able to use that function...

Comment: Neither of those things seems to be on and I don't have access to the php.ini file...however I tried file_get_contents() on a different server and it worked just fine so I bet this is just some weird setting from the PHP configuration on the other server. Thanks for your help!